# How can i send notifications in a PWA?

Tags: typescript, next.js, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am currently building a progressive web app to help people diagnosed with ADHD get along in their daily lifes. You can see the app in [mindfuel.vercel.app](https://mindfuel.vercel.app/home) and in [github](https://github.com/mindfuel-app/MindFuel)

I am using a version of [t3 Stack](https://create.t3.gg/), so im building with Next.JS, TypeScript, tRPC, Prisma and NextAuth.js

As part of the aplication i would like to send the user notifications when for example they forget to set a task as done after certain time has passed.

My questions are:
-which tools could i use for building a notifications system?
-where can i find tutorials or documentation for this tools?

I have already tried using firebase, but when i tried initializing firebase i got "navigator is not defined"
and that the browser is not authorized to use the API. You can see more of this on [this repo branch](https://github.com/mindfuel-app/MindFuel/tree/trying-firebase)

[error unhandledRejection: Error [FirebaseError]: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aZZd.png)

[Server Error. ReferenceError: navigator is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9us6.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).